# How to convert this MS SQL numeric value to a date

Tags: sql-server, date, type-conversion

Should be an easy convert, but cast and convert are failing me.

The value I am trying to convert is: 1509180600
Other examples are 1572256200, 5150938920

I have a very large number of records and many fields where dates have been stored like this. The system is being replaced, which means thankfully, this problem will go. But need to know what the values are before wiping them!

Comment: Can you explain what those numbers mean?  How are we supposed to know how to convert some random number into a date?

Comment: *Might* be easy if we knew what dates these examples are *meant* to relate to.

Comment: the numbers fields are warranty start dates, end dates, purchase date, service dates. For assedt inventories. Sorry fopr being so vague.

Comment: We're not asking what the dates are from...we're asking what format they're in?  How can you convert 0123456789 into a date?  Is it the number of seconds since some magical start date like the year 1500 C.E.?  Do the first 2 digits represent a day of the month, the next to the month of the year, and so on?  See what i'm getting at?  Without knowing *what* they mean, there's no way to answer this question.

Comment: The original data are stored as integers  in the table. Something went weird when the table was created. The database name in the server is simply 'Mdb', half the table name are prefixed with 'usp'... Good job it is going!

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a Unix timestamp.  You can convert it by adding seconds to 1970-01-01:

```
select dateadd(second, col, '1970-01-01')
. . .
```

Comment: that work perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: mmh, I used your same kind of reasoning, but I was blocked because while SELECT dateadd(s,1509180600,'19700101 05:00:00:000') give a value (future) of 2017-10-28 13:50,  the value 5150938920 doesn't seem to follow this rule

Comment: Why would you start at 5 a.m.?  Unix time stamps are measured in UTC.  I would convert to a datetime in UTC first, and then make any changes you want for the timestamp.  Putting the base value at anything other than "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" seems misleading to me.

Comment: @etsa . . . I cannot explain why *your* data would have a timestamp in the year 2133.  It could be a data error.  Or perhaps it is actually valid.

Comment: @Gordon: they are not MY data (I am not the questioner...) Bye